# IntelliJ doesn't recognize the maven plugins

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

The `pom.xml` file in the project using IntelliJ IDE doesn't recognize the maven plugins. I remove the maven and re-install it and also, download a new version of the IntelliJ IDE. The pom.xml file look file the following,

[image]

This is how the maven looks file in the IntelliJ:

[image]

The `mvn -version` return the output in the terminal:

```
mvn -version 

Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /Users/chaklader/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 14.0.2, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /Users/chaklader/.sdkman/candidates/java/14.0.2.j9-adpt
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Does anyone have hints what is the issue here?

Comment: The bigger actual question is do your Maven plugins work as expected?  Quite often, I will notice in IntelliJ that it's smart syntax highlighting won't work correctly, e.g. sometimes I a red underline in a `pom.xml` file, yet the build and application will still work properly.  What is your failure here?

Comment: Works fine in my IntelliJ.  It's you, not the IDE.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to make JAR with all the dependencies.

Comment: @duffymo Everything was working till yesterday, so not to sure how do I reach here.

Comment: Start by adding the <version> tag for each one.  I don't see it.  
Did I miss it?   When IntelliJ highlights something in red, I believe it.  If everything looks right and it still doesn't work, invalidate your caches and restart.  Sometimes the caches cause false negatives.

Comment: After I add the version and re-start the IDE by invalidating the cache, the issue is solved.